# Issues with Datastax Cassandra driver default load balancing policy

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax

As documented, this is the TokenAware(DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy). My cluster config looks like the following

```
lazy val session = {
val poolOptions = new PoolingOptions()
poolOptions.setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, config.getInt("pooling.max-local"))
poolOptions.setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.LOCAL, config.getInt("pooling.min-local"))
poolOptions.setMaxConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, config.getInt("pooling.max-remote"))
poolOptions.setCoreConnectionsPerHost(HostDistance.REMOTE, config.getInt("pooling.min-remote"))
Cluster.builder.addContactPoints(hosts)
    .withPoolingOptions(poolOptions)
    .build
    .connect
}
```

My Cluster looks like this:

DC1

10.dc1.rac1.ip1

10.dc1.rac2.ip1

DC2

10.dc2.rac1.ip1

10.dc2.rac2.ip1

Application is running on a 5th unrelated machine. Issue seems to be related to localDc auto discovery. According to the source code, the driver should detect local DC as the first node in the hosts list.  Here's what appears to happen:

- If hosts = [ 10.dc1.rac1.ip1, 10.dc2.rac1.ip1 ], app will succeed on a 50/50 basis with NoHostAvailableException. Local Dc will be either "dc1" or "dc2"
- If hosts = [ 10.dc1.rac1.ip1, 10.dc1.rac2.ip1 ], app will fail consistently with NoHostAvailableException. Local Dc will incorrectly be "dc2". Same is true if I use the other 2 machines. Note location of the app has not changed.
- If I manually set localDc in the builder, everything works as desired. This shouldn't matter though as the advertised functionality should be able to fall back to another datacenter.

Also the driver appears to be trying to connect to localhost though there is no cassandra instance running and no mention of it in the config. All of this would appear at first glance to be a bug, but considering the simplicity of my config and the seasoned nature of the datastax driver I'd be surprised.

EDIT: Apologies, should have mention i'm using 3.0.0

Comment: Which version of the driver are you using ?

Comment: It's possible the driver is trying localhost because the rpc_address / broadcast_rpc_address in  cassandra.yaml on one of your nodes is set to localhost.  Can you confirm whether or not this is the case?

In addition you should also take a look at the system.peers table by cqlsh'ing into each host individually and running 'select * from system.peers' to see what the rpc_address and data_center value is for each peer according to each node.

Answer (score 0):

Andy Tolbert above had the correct answer for anyone that is looking.  Unfortunately it seems the default settings (and any setting other than explicitly configuring the correct address on each machine for that matter) don't allow you to simultaneously accept connections from local and remote hosts.